# JNA Callback Issues

Tags: java, jna

I want to call a DLL file, having successfully created the interface with JNA studio. I have a problem calling the necessary methods.

Please see the interface below.

```
public interface MME9000Library extends Library {

    public static final String JNA_LIBRARY_NAME =LibraryExtractor.getLibraryPath(" MME9000", true, TP9000Library.class);  

    public static final NativeLibrary JNA_NATIVE_LIB NativeLibrary.getInstance(TP9000Library.JNA_LIBRARY_NAME,      MangledFunctionMapper.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);    

    public static final VLibrary INSTANCE = (MME9000Library)Native.loadLibrary(TP9000Library.JNA_LIBRARY_NAME,       MME9000Library.class, MangledFunctionMapper.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);     

    public static final int TP_TRUE = (int)-1;
    public static final int TP_NOT_SUPPORTED_IMAGE = (int)-4;
    public static final int TP_FALSE = (int)-2;
    public static final int TP_DLL_NOT_LOADED = (int)-3;

    public interface pfnSetLogPathFile extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer pLogFile);
    };
    public interface pfnGetConnectedDevices extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(int dwDevice, IntByReference pdwCount);
    };

    public static class LPRECT extends PointerType {
        public LPRECT(Pointer address) {
            super(address);
        }
        public LPRECT() {
            super();
        }
    };
    public static class LPBYTE extends PointerType {
        public LPBYTE(Pointer address) {
            super(address);
        }
        public LPBYTE() {
            super();
        }
    };
    public static class HANDLE extends PointerType {
        public HANDLE(Pointer address) {
            super(address);
        }
        public HANDLE() {
            super();
        }
    };
    public static class LPWSTR extends PointerType {
        public LPWSTR(Pointer address) {
            super(address);
        }
        public LPWSTR() {
            super();
        }
    };

    public static class LPDWORD extends PointerType {
        public LPDWORD(Pointer address) {
            super(address);
        }
        public LPDWORD() {
            super();
        }
    };

}
```

For example if I want to call `pfnGetConnectedDevices` interface (although it's a method in the C++ header file) how do i go about it?

Comment: How do you get the function pointer in the first place?

Comment: @ technomage the function pointers were generated from the C++ header file with Jnaeratorstudio

Comment: If you were to write the code you want in C, what would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function which takes a function pointer as an argument, then you do this:

```
pfnGetConnectedDevices myCallback = new pfnGetConnectedDevices() {
    public int apply(int dwDevice, IntByReference pdwCount) {
        // your code here
    }
};
lib.myFunction(myCallback);
```

Comment: thanks for your help on this, i have no function that takes a function pointer as an argument. with reference to the code you posted above , does  the code  below make sense ?

Comment: pfnListDevices dvList = new pfnListDevices(){

            @Override
            public int apply(IntByReference pArg1, Pointer pArg2, int pArg3){
                return pArg1.getValue();
            }
                  };
              System.out.println("list device is "+dvList.apply(pdwCount, Pointer.NULL,  0x01000000));

Comment: You can't just create a `Callback` (i.e. function pointer) on the Java side without mapping it to a native address.

Answer (score 0):

```
pfnListDevices dvList = new pfnListDevices(){

    @Override
    public int apply(IntByReference pArg1, Pointer pArg2, int pArg3){
        return pArg1.getValue();
    }
};
System.out.println("list device is "+dvList.apply(pdwCount, Pointer.NULL,  0x01000000));
```